# Java Swing paint() Twice Show Once when Full Screen

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a small game using Java Swing. A class `Game` extends `JPanel` and implements `ActionListener`, a `Timer` in it calls `repaint()` to update the screen, then create a `JFrame` and add `Game` to it.

Then I noticed when I make the window full screen, the screen is updated once when `paint()` is called twice. This is weird! Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an SSCCE, the example creates a variable `count`, and paint count then `count+=1;` in `repaint()`. When not full screen, it shows `0 1 2 3 4`... When full screen, it shows `4 6 8 10`...

Example code here:

```java
package test.swing.FullScreenDropFrameRate;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int count = 0;

    public Game() {
        new Timer(1000, this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // bg
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);

        // info string
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.drawString(""+count, 0, 30);

        count += 1;

        g.dispose();
    }
}

public class TestFullScreenFrameRate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Snake");
        jf.setBounds(100, 35, 800, 600); // x, y, width, height
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(new Game());
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you making the window full screen ?

Comment: By clicking the top, right button.

Comment: 1) `public void paint(Graphics g) {` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` for any `JComponent`, and should immediately call the `super` method to erase past drawings and draw the background etc. 2) `new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 30)` would better be `new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 30)` 3) *"This is weird!"* Not really. The JVM will call for a repaint whenever it thinks it is necessary. Given it is not within the control of the programmer, don't rely on it being called at the times you expect.

Comment: You may also want to increment your counter inside `actionPerformed` rather than inside the painting method .

Comment: .. 4) `g.dispose();` don't dispose of a `Graphics` object unless you explicitly created it.

Comment: So I shouldn't do anything inside paint(Graphics g) or paintComponent(Graphics g) except painting?

Comment: This sounds like a (probably dangerous) [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you trying to use the `paint` method as a way to update the game state at a predictable steady pace? If so, then that's very wrong!. Update the game state in a scheduled executor at a predictable pace, then call swing's `repaint`. If graphics are too heavy, you will get lower FPS but the game pace will stay the same. Remember to use proper memory guards in a multi-threaded environment

Comment: Please don't include answer in the question body itself. Instead, please write an answer and accept it. Remember that [so] is a **Q&A site**, not a discussion forum!

Comment: OK, wrote it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem is that I shouldn't put anything which updates the game state in `paint()`. Java calls it when needed. Thanks to @Andrew Thompson.

Some other mistakes, improvements and documentation:

1)[Documentation - JComponent - paint()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)): Invoked by Swing to draw components. ...  A subclass that just wants to specialize the UI (look and feel) delegate's paint method should just override paintComponent.

2)[Documentation - Font - SERIF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#SERIF): A String constant for the canonical family name of the logical font "Serif". It is useful in Font construction to provide compile-time verification of the name.

3)[Oracle - about Painting](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callback)

4)[Documentation - Graphics - dispose()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose()): For efficiency, programmers should call dispose when finished using a Graphics object only if it was created directly from a component or another Graphics object.

5)[A Java Game Tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9qMm3JbOH0#t=22m33s): Bad example! DO NOT use `paint()` and `g.dispose()` here!!!